# Library path not found (google-play-services_lib)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

Im using eclipe, 
Following the EXACT guilds of developers.android.com , just doesn't work.

I just want to add the google-play-services_lib to my project, apperently eclipse is to stupid to find the path.

When i click properties > android > add project > google-play-services_lib it adds the library in the list, gives me also a green sign, everthing well.
Then i click apply, and nothing happens, nothing added to depedencies... 
When i check properties > android again it tells me it didn't find the path i gave...

Though i did multiple times exactly the same with other projects, and i just could add this library!...
Whats wrong..

Ive a second library which is the facebook_sdk, but this can't be the problem right?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Google Play Services library on a different drive to the project? There is an issue if they are located on different drives which causes eclipse to not find the path.

Copy the Google Play Services library to the same drive, and reimport into eclipse and see if that works.

Otherwise try deleting the play services project in eclipse and reimporting it. Sometimes if the SDK (and play services) has been updated, eclipse needs it to be reimported.

Comment: I removed , imported the project multiple times, also tryed multiple things to replace needing to import it this way, but nothing works well. I was thinking about your comment about the different drive thing. Its true that my workspace, android sdk (Where the googleplaything comes fromg), I think this is the case! I will definitely look into it. Though im not sure why it works not in my project and it works well in other projects i use..